# Java Send Console Input To Sub Process After Sub Process Has Started

Tags: java, windows, resources, console, exec

The program I am working on pulls from the console while it is running in a thread running next to the main thread (checking if the scanner has a next line before reading), at one point I need to start a sub process which also needs to read from the console. I Have a class for running commands and getting their output and passing input into them from the parent process's console. This works fine when run from Eclipse, but if I put it into a jar file and run it from the Windows console I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command
    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method), 
    java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source), 
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source), 
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source), 
    bin.Exec_assist.run(Exec.java:172), 
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error occurs as soon as I press enter not matter what other keys I press, also the console doesn't let me type anything. Here's the piece of code the passes the console input into the sub process:

```
public void run(){

        byte[] b = new byte[8064 * 8];
        int r;
        is = System.in;

        try{


            while(run.isAlive()){//run is a pointer to an object passed in though the constructor, the object it points to is from a class that I use to determine if the process is still running

                if(is.available() > 0){

                    r = is.read(b, 0, b.length);
                    os.write(b, 0, r);//os is the output stream for the process being run, also passed in through the constructor
                    os.flush();

                }else{

                    Thread.sleep(500);

                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace()

        }

}
```

I've tried turning is into a scanner and using hasNext() on that but that only causes new problems and doesn't fix the old ones, it does allow me to type in the Windows console but pressing enter still causes the same error.

Comment: This is an error message from the Windows runtime. Trying to track down something that seems applicable to your case, but it's an issue of running out of Windows resources. Does the problem occur if you make your buffer smaller?

Comment: I can't find anything that's directly on-topic. It appears that *some* resource is running out, but I'm not a Windows person and don't know how to find out what. Retagging.

Comment: @chrylis I'll try shrinking the buffer size, but I don't think that's the issue, Process Explorers doesn't show a spike of any recourse usage when I get to that part of the program.

Comment: Well thanks man... I honestly never thought of the buffer size but that does the trick.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're doing I/O in big blocks like this, it's probably worth using NIO. The interface isn't any more complicated, and it's faster and more flexible.